# Wakanda Server 10 on Amazon EC2, cannot listen for connections on port 8080 or secure port 4433 on all IP addresses

Tags: amazon-ec2, wakanda

I have installed wakanda server on an Amazon EC2 server running ubuntu by following this utube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSQODnB7wRU .

Now the video is for an older version but I have followed along successfully until I actually launch wakanda on the server. This is what I get in the console:

Welcome to Wakanda Server 10 build 10.187175

Publishing "DefaultSolution" solution

The solution's log file will be stored in the "/home/ubuntu/.Wakanda Server/UserCache/Wakanda Server/DefaultSolution-1882/Logs/" folder

- The Administration Web Server cannot listen for connections on port 8080 or secure port 4433 on all IP addresses
  You can customize the Administration Web Server's ports with the "--admin-port" and "--admin-ssl-port" options

, then when I try to log into it via the browser it says the connection dropped!   Any help would be much appreciated, it seams I need to restrict the IP addresses which can access, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Your wakanda server tried and failed to listen on 8080 and/or 4433

Check the following things:

- Are the ports 8080 and/or 4433 used by other processes? (`sudo netstat -tapen | grep :8080`, if a result is found, then yes another process uses 8080. Check 4433 also)
- You may found that wakanda server is already running as a service:

  - yes you should use this service (create and edit `/etc/default/wakanda`, add `WAKANDA_SOLUTION_AT_STARTUP=your_path` and restart with `sudo /etc/init.d/wakanda restart`)
  - or to continue starting it manually, stop the service first (`sudo /etc/init.d/wakanda stop`)
- Has the current user the right to listen on those ports? (try running the server with sudo just to check, then use authbind or equivalent)
- Can you use alternative ports? (use --admin-port and --admin-ssl-port wakanda server options)

wakanda-server --help will give you the list of options available, especially --solution=VALUE to provide the path to your solution.